# Python how to format requests data

Tags: python, python-requests

I would like to format my request data field.
I tried many methods but I couldn't

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Accept-Language': 'tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Origin': 'https://www.example.com',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://www.example.com/',
}


data = '{ "loginId": "mailadress@hotmail.com", "password": "password123"}'


response = s.post('https://auth-api.example.com/login', headers=headers, data=data)
```

I tried:

```
data = '{ "loginId": "{}", "password": "{}"}'.format(liste[0],liste[1])
```

Also:

```
data = "'{ "loginId": "{}", "password": "{}"}'".format(liste[0],liste[1])
```

**quote = ' " '**

```
data = quote + '{ "loginId": "{}", "password": "{}"}' + quote.format(liste[0],liste[1])
```

So how can I format data field?

Comment: Is `data` really supposed to be a `str` or maybe a `dict`?

Comment: @C14L i will put mail adress and password for data

Comment: If you want to pass in a dict ... pass in a dict.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/) of the *post* function specifies that *data* must be a dictionnary, list of tuples, bytes, or file-like object.

So, try:

```
data = {"loginId": liste[0], "password": list[1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the requests module like this:

```
import requests

try:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
   data = requests.post('https://auth-api.example.com/login', auth=("mailadress@hotmail.com", "password123"), headers=headers, verify=False)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:

    print e                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    print ("unable to run request on %s " % (url) )    
    continue
```